# jQuery Validation Plugin Not Recognizing Valid Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, validation

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm using the [jQuery Validation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation) plugin. This is my jQuery code:

```
$('#form-login').validate({
    onsubmit: true,
    onfocusout: false,
    errorClass: 'invalid',
    wrapper: 'li',
    errorLabelContainer: '#login-error-list ul',
    errorContainer: '#login-error-list',
    highlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find('label[for=' + element.id + ']')
            .addClass(errorClass);
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        $(element.form).find('label[for=' + element.id + ']')
            .removeClass(errorClass);
    },
    rules: {
        username: 'required',
        password: 'required'
    },
    messages: {
        username: 'Please enter your username.',
        password: 'Please enter your password.'
    }
});
```

I followed the API Documentation very closely while writing this. However, no matter what input is entered (whether it's none, or anything valid), it still throws an error as if the username and/or password were never entered in. You can see for yourself on [this login page](http://www.wowgeeks.com/login.php).

Anyone know what the problem could be?

P.S.: I should add the HTML code that generates the form and error container:

```
<p>Already have an account with us? Then log in!</p>
<form action="login.php" method="post" id="form-login">
<input type="hidden" name="success_page" value="" />
<div class="group">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" title="Username" maxlength="20" min="6" max="20" />
</div>
<div class="group">
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" title="Password" min="6" />
</div>
<div id="login-error-list" class="group" style="display: none;">
    <p>Errors:</p>
    <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a long shot - but it could be an issue with jQuery 1.6 (released earlier this week). I know they changed the way that attr() works, and it's used pretty heavily in the Validation plugin. Maybe try linking to 1.5.2.

Comment: I used 1.5.2 instead of grabbing the most recent version from jQuery's web site, but the problem persists, as you can still see on the login page I linked to in the original post. (Uprated your comment because it made sense, and I had problems with attr() just the other day.)

Comment: i think its working. I used the following plugin <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.8/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> 
Just try with that js file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove your custom messages and you'll see what the real issue is:

http://jsfiddle.net/DLcLJ/

You have both inputs set to only accept numbers >6.

I'm assuming what you intended was minlength.  Replace both min attributes with minlength and remove the max on username.

Comment: Oops! I thought those were new HTML5 attributes. I blame Dreamweaver CS5 for having them pop-up while typing, and myself for making assumptions. It works now — thanks!